# Cannot delete files from Dropbox(from iPhone app)

Tags: ios, iphone, file, dropbox, delete-file

I'm trying to delete files from my dropbox. I have implemented the swipe delete behaviour. This 'swipe-delete' deletes the files from the tableView only. Next time I upload, I can see the 'deleted' files back and also when I check my dropbox account on my PC, those files never get deleted. They're always there even immediately after the file disappears from the tableView.

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {    
      return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
  }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath :(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {                
    [self.itemArray  removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];        

    [aTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];

    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];     
}
```

Comment: Done, added code. Please check.

Comment: I dont see any code that deletes the contents of the dropbox

Answer (score 1):

You're code only shows you're deleting the entry from the table view. There is no code that actually deletes from the file system, eg. by using

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filepath error:&error];
```

Comment: Should I put this in the commitEditingStyle method?

Comment: I would recommend handling this asynchronously so the UI doesn't halt if it takes several seconds for the file to be deleted. The trigger could be put in commitEditingStyle.

Comment: How do you know the file exists? I presume you iterate over the known files and build your index somewhere in your code where the path is known, or do the index just magically come into existence?

Comment: I have (NSIndexPath*) as input to the function. How do I obtain the filePath? Because if I pass indexPath then I get the warning 'NSFileManager may not respond to removeItemAtPath:error' and my program gets SIGABRT when I press Delete.

Comment: Store the path internally in your itemArray when you build the index.

Comment: because only the files that are present are shown in the tableview. So that guarantees its existense. Could you show me how to do what you're saying please?

Comment: You are already referring to self.itemArray so I presume you already have code that populates this array with the files you found. I also presum you are storing the name of the file in this array, so just add another key/value pair with the path.

Comment: How do you add a key/value pair with the path? I'm sorry, but I've never done this before.

Comment: [itemPlist setObject:path forKey:@"path"]

Comment: Thank you. Since i'm not downloading files from dropbox, I don't think NSFileManager would work. I would need to use dropbox APIs to delete files on dropbox. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The above discussion(NSFileManager) removes files only from the device. For deleting files on dropbox, we must use deleteFilePath and deletePathFailedWithError.